# How to create a Unicode txt file in C++

Tags: c++, file, unicode

There are four kind of encoding options when creating a .txt file in Windows.

- ANSI
- UNICODE(litte endian)
- UNICODE(big endian)
- UTF-8

[image: Text File Encoding Option]

C standard library supports this option, by using `FILE`.

[image: C STL]

```
FILE* file;
file = _wfopen(L"test.txt", L"wt+,ccs=UTF-16LE");
```

It has been working great, but I found there is no parameter for this in `std::ofstream`.

```
wofstream myfile;
myfile.open("example.txt", ?????????);
```

So, I want to know how to create files like this in C++. Is there any solution for this in C++ STL?

Comment: The term `STL` is used to refer only to those parts of the Standard Library that deals with *iterators* and *containers* and *algorithms*, not files. **see:** https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#S-glossary

Comment: [What's this STL vs C++ Standard Library fight all about?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-this-stl-vs-c-standard-library-fight-all-about)

Comment: The C standard library doesn't support anything like that. Your Windows C runtime library that comes with MSVC does. There's absolutely nothing standard about it.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/codecvt/codecvt_utf16/

Comment: I'm talking about the file saving option, not the contents in txt file.

Comment: Please use a tag in this format: @ee_do to answer a specific user's comment. The user will get a message, and everyone will understand the flow of the conversation.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with C++11, the standard C++ library allows to generate UTF16 text files with the following steps:

- build a locale using the C++11 class `std::codecvt_utf16` - you can specify endianness in constructor
- open a file using a `std::wofstream` in which you will write unicode text
- just `imbue` the locale into the wide stream and start writing, optionnaly starting with a Byte Order Mark character (U+FEFF)

Here is an example adapted from the [page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/codecvt/codecvt_utf16/) referenced by @HansPassant in its comment:

```
// codecvt_utf16: writing unicode string as UTF-16
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <string>
#include <codecvt>
#include <fstream>

int main ()
{
  std::wstring str ( { 0xa8, 0xa9 });

  std::locale loc (std::locale(), new std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t>);
  std::basic_ofstream<wchar_t> ofs ("test.txt");
  ofs.imbue(loc);

  std::cout << "Writing to file (UTF-16)... ";
  ofs << (wchar_t) 0xfeff; // BOM
  ofs << str;
  std::cout << "done!\n";

  return 0;
}
```

You get an utf16 file starting with a little endian BOM and containing `èé`

(hexadecimal dump:

```
$ od -xc test.txt
0000000      fffe    a800    a900
         376 377  \0 250  \0 251
```

)

Comment: Credits should remain to @HansPassant that gave the reference in its comment

Comment: If you use `new std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, generate_header>` instead, you don't have to write a BOM manually, one will be written automatically.

Comment: In any case, if you are not using C++11, you can still use `std::wofstream` to produce UTF-16 encoded files, you don't really need to imbue a locale to accomplish that.  On Windows, writing a `wchar_t` to a `std::wofstream` outputs UTF-16 encoded data. That being said, `imbue()` and `std::locale` are available in pre-C++11 versions. It is `std::codecvt_utf16` that was added in C++11. You can create and imbue UTF-16 locales in earlier versions.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Thank you for the clear explanations. You,re saying using std::wofstream and a wchar_t is enough to create unicode encoded data. That is true, but the data means contents in the file, the file itself is still ANSI encoded. So, can you show me how to accomplish that without std::codecvt_utf16?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau and  If I use "generate_header", it creates a big endian UTF-16 encoded file. To produce a little endian file, I have to use "little_endian" instead of "generate_header".

Comment: @ee_do: You can use both via the OR (`|`) operator: `new std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, generate_header | little_endian>`

Comment: "can still use std::wofstream to produce UTF-16 encoded files" The standard says nothing about how wofstreams are encoded. "On Windows, writing a wchar_t to a std::wofstream outputs UTF-16 encoded data" Not with commonly available compilers like MSVC or GCC (unless you imbue a locale with appropriate codecvt).

Answer (score 1):

There is no "C STL". STL stands for Standard Template Library. C does not have templates. You may be referring to the C standard library and C++ standard library.

The C standard library has no functions for "creating unicode" or converting text to or from unicode. There is no `_wfopen` in the C standard libray. You're using a function from the Microsoft C Run-Time Library.

The C++ library does have an API to convert between (UTF-8 and UTF-16) and (UTF-8 and UTF-32) and (system native wide and system native multibyte) encodings: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt

There is hardly any other support for unicode in the standard library. You must take care that the string that you're writing is in the encoding that you want it to be and you must explicitly write a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) if you need to.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about Standard Library, It's my mistake. Thank you!